# SELECT error querying

Tags: mysql

What could be wrong with this line:

```
'$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (rlat => '".$latmin."' AND rlat <= '".$latmax."')      AND (rlon >= '".$lonmin."' AND rlon <= '".$lonmax."')";'
```

> Error: Error in query: SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (r_lat =>
>   '55.4655951769' AND r_lat <= '55.496987423') AND (r_lon >=
>   '25.5338700398' AND r_lon <= '25.5989507602'). You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near '=> '55.4655951769'
>   AND r_lat <= '55.496987423') AND (r_lon >= '25.5338700398' AN' at line
>   1...

Thanks!

Comment: SHould those floats really be quoted as strings?

Comment: Do be sure you're [properly escaping everything](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Using string concatenation is a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 3):

`=>` isn't a known [operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/non-typed-operators.html).  If you want the [greater than or equal comparison operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_greater-than-or-equal), then you are after `>=`.

Incidentally, you might find that your query can be written more concisely with the [`BETWEEN ... AND ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   messages
WHERE  rlat BETWEEN $latmin AND $latmax
   AND rlon BETWEEN $lonmin AND $lonmax
```

You should also investigate passing variables into your SQL by way of [parameters to prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496).